# javascript function return without semicolon

Tags: javascript, return-value

if i want to write (to save 4 spaces indentation, or what ever reason):

```
return
   someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;
```

return will be treated as 'return;' and something that is ok in all c-alike languages, will fail in javascript.

is there some workarround for this strange behaviour?

**update**: maybe shortest solution would be like this (simillar answers below)

```
return 0||
    someLongLineWxpressionReturnValue;
```

Comment: you can wrap the expression in parenthesis, with the opening one on the same line as the return

Comment: @NickParsons yes that is one way... i just wondering if there is something that do not involve changing line2.... (it can be + for integer returning functions)

Comment: Do your function do other things before the return? Or does it just return an expression?

Comment: @NickParsons yes, i was looking for anywhere-solution. i think bellow answers lead to 2 good results: 'return 0||' ... or  'return globalDummyVar =' ... for first line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That happens because a semicolon is inserted automatically after the `return` statement, making it:

```
return;
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;
```

If you want `return` to be coupled with the next line, you need to start an expression on the `return` line.

Ideas:

```
// a natural way of doing this
return (
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue
);

// or, if you don't want to add parenthesis

return "" + // if the expression is a string
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;

return 0 + // if the expression is a number
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;

return true && // if the expression is a boolean
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;
```

The last example should work regardless of the type of `someLongLineExpressionReturnValue`, because the first part of the expression will be evaluated to `true`, then `&&` will return the second part of the expression, which is `someLongLineExpressionReturnValue`.

I do recommend the more natural way of doing this, since the others can become a maintenance issue in the future, and you may at one point end up wondering why you did that.

Comment: did you mean 'false ||' in last example... btw not sure but is it possible that " false || " will work for anything? in php it will probably work because return will get value AND type of second opperand

Comment: @MetNP, right, thanks, updated to `true &&`. Yes, that will work for anything. I expect this to become a maintenance issue in the future though, so I'd still recommend using the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to surround the return value with parentheses (function f below).

Another is to put the long expression value into a variable and return the variable (function g below).

But perhaps the best solution for your question is to OR it with `false` (function h below). Since `false` is never `true` it will return the value after the `||` on the following line.

```js
someLongLineExpressionReturnValue = "hello";

function f() {
  return (
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue
  )
}
function g() {
  const result =
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;
  return result;
}
function h() {
  return false ||
    someLongLineExpressionReturnValue;
}

console.log("f()",f());
console.log("g()",g());
console.log("h()",h());
```

Comment: 'return dummy =' in first line would also be corect answer with problem that it will leave (polute) global var space with variable dummy. but that will be closest to perfect workaround

Comment: I added a function h() with a 3rd way (probably best)